# In .net core how to download a static file with special extension in web root?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1)  and [this one](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html) can not handle Serve files in web root (.net core 3.1).

There is a CB folder in the webroot folder and I can browse any txt or png file it works fine but when I want to download an apk file it doesn't work and browser message files not found.

this is my folders structure:

```
-wwwroot
   -CB
     myfile.apk
```

installed “Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles” and used:

```
 app.UseStaticFiles();
```

tested URL:

```
http://localhost:51405/cb/myfile.apk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the second article, it explicity states to configure `UseStaticFiles()` options via its parameter and specify that static files should be served even if the file type is unknown.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
    });
```

Like the article states, however, this is a pretty big security risk. Proceed with caution.